# how can i use paginate() function with db::select

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, pagination

First of all, I'm interested in how to use the paginate function with a simple query.
for example, I have this query:

```
$query = "SELECT 
 dw.id,
 w.word,
 d.definition,
 dw.user_id,
 IF(IFNULL(dw.definition_id, 0) = 0,
    (SELECT COUNT(phrase_id) 
     FROM phrase_word wp1 WHERE wp1.user_id = dw.user_id AND wp1.word_id = dw.word_id),
    (SELECT COUNT(phrase_id)
     FROM phrase_word wp2 WHERE wp2.user_id = dw.user_id AND wp2.word_id = dw.word_id AND wp2.definition_id = dw.definition_id)
   ) phrases_count
 FROM definition_word AS dw
 INNER JOIN words AS w ON w.id  = dw.word_id 
 LEFT JOIN definitions AS d ON d.id = dw.definition_id
 WHERE dw.user_id = 2";
```

I Can't use the paginate method in this way.
`$unknown_words = DB::select($query)->paginate(5);`

Or if it's possible how to convert

```
"IF(IFNULL(dw.definition_id, 0) = 0,
    (SELECT COUNT(phrase_id) 
     FROM phrase_word wp1 WHERE wp1.user_id = dw.user_id AND wp1.word_id = dw.word_id),
    (SELECT COUNT(phrase_id)
     FROM phrase_word wp2 WHERE wp2.user_id = dw.user_id AND wp2.word_id = dw.word_id AND wp2.definition_id = dw.definition_id)
   ) phrases_count";
```

this piece of the query into a query builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a better option you can use laravel joins select and table method and you could achieve your desire output as below.

```
 $unknown_words = DB::table('definition_word as dw')
 ->join('words as w', 'w.id', '=', 'dw.word_id')
 ->leftJoin('definitions as d', 'd.id', '=', 'dw.definition_id')
 ->select(
    'dw.id',
    'w.word',
    'd.definition',
    'dw.user_id',
        DB::raw('IF(IFNULL(dw.definition_id, 0) = 0,
            (SELECT COUNT(phrase_id) 
            FROM phrase_word wp1 WHERE wp1.user_id = dw.user_id AND wp1.word_id = dw.word_id),
            (SELECT COUNT(phrase_id)
            FROM phrase_word wp2 WHERE wp2.user_id = dw.user_id AND wp2.word_id = dw.word_id AND wp2.definition_id = dw.definition_id)
        ) as phrases_count')
    )->where('dw.user_id', 2)->paginate(15)
```

Comment: Hello,  there is some problem  DB::raw('IF(IFNULL(dw.definition_id, 0) = 0, in this row.. it's says that  dw.definition_id is undefined...

Comment: would you please debug it using dump and run query into the database?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '=dw.definition_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `definition_word` as `dw` inner join `words` as `w` on `w`.`id` = `dw`.`word_id` left join `definitions` as `d` on `d`.`id` = `=dw`.`definition_id` where `dw`.`user_id` = 2)

here is the error... 

when I run query into the database it works but from code...

Comment: I have updated the code please check now, by mistake I have put a full stop(.) instead of a comma

Comment: Thank you.. you really help me!